# Submit form with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am very new to jquery and I have a confirm / cancel message box which works very well except I can't get any of the posted values from the form.  I know it is me and my lack of understanding of jquery but I would be very grateful if someone could look at my code and tell me what needs to be in the function(result) so that when the form posts to it's self I can use if(isset['$_post['delete_job'])) in order to run a php script.

My form...

```
<form id="del_job" onsubmit="return del_job()" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<div id="deleted"><button type="submit"  name="delete_job" title="Delete Job" style="float:left; border:none; cursor:pointer" ><img src="img/delete.jpg" /></button> Delete</a></div>
</form>
```

My Jquery...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#del_job').submit(function(ev){

      $.msgbox("Are you sure?", {
        type: "confirm", 
        buttons: [
          {type: "submit", value: "Yes"},
          {type: "cancel", value: "No"}
        ]
      }, function(result) {
        if (result && result=='Yes') {
          $('#del_job').send();
        }
      });

      ev.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like all you're really doing is popping up a confirm box. Is the goal to submit the form with ajax without reloading the page and get the data back in a success function, or just to prompt the user before running the native submit function which will reload the page ?

Comment: Hi, the goal is to prompt the user before running the native submit function and reloading the page.  Eg, user presses submit button, page self posts and runs a php script at the top of the page if the submit button name isset

Comment: Did you try replacing `send()` with `submit()` like the answer below suggests, and where is the `$.msgbox` function coming from ?

Comment: I did try replacing send() with submit() and although the page refreshes I'm not able to get the $_post value using  if(isset($_POST['delete_job'])){$did_it_work = 'yes';}..the $.msgbox function is an external script which styles the confirm box and makes it drop with a bounce, that's all

Comment: Am I wrong in using the if(isset....) ?

Comment: You could just try printing $_POST and see what it contains ?

Comment: I have and it contains nothing

Comment: Well, that seems to be the problem then ?

Comment: ok, if the form submits ok afterwards if(isset($_POST['delete_job'])){ $please = 'yes'; echo $please; } should print 'yes'} but it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the problem!

It seems that BUTTON elements are not part of the submitted POST data, I guess that makes sense because they hold no actual value. So here you have two choices, you can switch your `<button>` to `<input type="submit" name="delete_job" value="Delete" />`, but the limitation here is you cannot have an image in the button.

The other option is to add a hidden field and use `isset()` on that. To do this simply add `<input name="del_job_submit" type="hidden" value="1" />` to your form and use `isset($_POST['del_job_submit'])` to check if the form was submitted.

Comment: That just causes the message box to keep appearing, you click yes and it pops up again...

Comment: @tatty27 Okay, that's progress, I've changed the HTML code as well, try changing both the HTML and JavaScript to what I've provided

Comment: Thanks, I've done that but the value $please from if(isset($_POST['delete_job'])){$please = 'yes';} is still empty

Comment: so far this is it  if(isset($_POST['delete_job'])){$please = $_POST['foo']; echo $please;} (I added a hidden table to the form <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="fecking work" /> to see if I could get something different to work)  The original php before adding the hidden table was just if(isset($_POST['delete_job'])){$please = 'yes'; echo $please;}.  This is at the top of the page

Comment: BTW, I'm very grateful that you are taking the time to help me

Comment: Ok, I'm trying the code out on my computer now. Give me a few mins.

Comment: @tatty27 Hey, I tried it out and I think I've found the problem. Try making those changes and see if it helps.